# Running electron app get an error 'the futex facility returned an unexpected error'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, ubuntu-18.04, environment

I am trying to launch any electron application. When I just try to run app with `npm start` I get an error `` Running as root without `--no-sandbox` is not supported `` I edit start script from `"electron ."` to `"electron --no-sandbox ."` and get the new error `The futex facility returned an unexpected error code./mnt/c/Users/Oleg/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT`. I can't find the answer to this question on Google, help plase guys.
My environment is: Windows 10 2004,
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Node.js 12, Visual Studio Code

Comment: is it [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24211)?

Answer (score 2):

I recently just had this problem when trying to run my Electron application as well using WSL2.

Summary of items needed:

- XSERV running on Windows to Run Linux GUI Applications (e.g., your electron Application)
- Proper identification of DISPLAY from the remote WSL subsystem

### Get an XSERVER

I use https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/. Download and install.

### Ensure your display is properly identified

Run from your WSL terminal

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

#### Authorization Issue?

`Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified`

Look at the below GitHub issue for further understanding on creating a start script for your XSERVER on fixing your authorization issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4793#issuecomment-588321333

Note: I *didn't* have to perform to get my setup to work. The above DISPLAY command correctly identifies my host, so this one was unnecessary:

```
export DISPLAY=$WSL_IF_IP:0
```

Comment: thanks! and (note to self) make sure your x-server gets started up again after any reboot :)